# Parse data with XPath or CSS selector from Downloader Middleware using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to extract data from responses to make sure my proxy is not yet black listed (getting HTTP status is not sufficient).

To do so, I wrote a Downloader Middleware

```
class TestXPathMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        print(request.url)
        print(type(response))
        if (isinstance(response, HtmlResponse)):
            print('HtmlResponse, XPath should be available')
            print(response.encoding)
            print(response.xpath('//div'))
        return response
```

However, my crawler is not responding as expected. I would expect that response object received will be `scrapy.http.response.Response` as [read in the doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response) and I would expect being able to create a HtmlResponse from the Response object to use XPath.

What is actually happening?

Some responses catched in the middleware are `Response` but some other are directly `HtmlResponse`. (It seems that responses from the first parse method in the spider are `Response`, other (from deeper parsing method) are `HtmlResponse` instead. Why? I can't say but I would love :)

Second, I'm not able to extract data with XPath. It seems that I cannot decode the bytes from `response.body`. `response.encoding` is outputting `ascii`. I then tried to use `chardet` to determine the encoding to use, it outputs `None` in the middleware whereas it outputs `ISO-8859-1` in the spider's parse method. Why? One more time, I can't say but I would love!

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
Data transfered over HTTP are often compressed with gzip for example. My current downloader middleware was triggered before the `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware` that is actually decompressing response.

So, to make sure my custom process_response method is called after the response is being decompressed I need to put my `TestXPathMiddleware` before the `HttpCompressionMiddleware`. Once this is done, I can properly decode response.

Or I can disable `HttpCompressionMiddleware` with `COMPRESSION_ENABLE=False`. This will send HTTP request and ask for non compressed responses.

Hope this will help ;)